# SSH ClientAliveInterval specific to a user

Tags: openssh, sshd

I would like to know if there is a way to define different `ClientAliveInterval` and `ClientAliveCountMax` for different users.

For example, I have users that can access the shell and want to set `ClientAliveCountMax` to zero to them so that their session is closed if they are inactive even if the session is still running correctly.

But I have a user that is used to create ssh tunnels and I want these sessions to be kept opened and so set a non-zero `ClientAliveCountMax` for this one.

Is that possible ?

Thanks

Comment: Note that ClientAlive applies to _any_ SSH packet, _not_ just interactive-shell commands, so the interval would be equally satisfied by shell access and tunnel traffic.

Comment: But if for testing, I set `ClientAliveInterval` to 10 and `ClientAliveCountMax` to 0 and I open two shell sessions. I keep typing characters on one, and the other is well kicked after 10 seconds. So the question is not silly and they could differentiate according to the user. Seems like it is just not implemented though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible. This option is marked as a global in `sshd_config` and it means that you can't use it in `Match` block.

I can think only about alternative way of doing this by running two separate `sshd` services with different configuration on different ports and one would be dropping connections and one would not.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Didn't think of duplicating the service. I will try that :)